# Camunda API Assign and Count Task Count By Candidate Group

Tags: bpmn, camunda

I am creating a workflow in Camunda. I'd like to:

1. assign tasks to a group, other than a specific user
2. count the number of tasks per group.

I did not find any guideline from Camunda docs talking about assigning tasks to a group, so I tried [Add Identity Link](https://docs.camunda.org/manual/7.16/reference/rest/task/identity-links/post-identity-link/)

`POST /task/{{taskid}}/identity-links`

Request body:

```json
{"groupId": "teamA", "type": "candidate"}
```

However, when I try [Get Task Count By Candidate Group](https://docs.camunda.org/manual/7.16/reference/rest/task/post-query-count/)

`GET /task/report/candidate-group-count`

There was no task assigned to TeamA from the Response body, in contrast, all my desired tasks fell into the group null.

```json
[
    {
        "groupName": "accounting",
        "taskCount": 4
    },
    {
        "groupName": "sales",
        "taskCount": 2
    },
    {
        "groupName": null,
        "taskCount": 6
    }
]
```

Any advice on how to fix this?

**UPDATE 2022-02-11**

I think the issue might be caused by the version of camunda bpmn platform. After I downgrade the version from 7.17.0-alpha4 to 7.16, the issue is resolved.

Comment: That is strange - I tried to reproduce this, but with no success. It works as it should (Camunda Platform / v7.16.3-ee)

Comment: Works also on Camunda Platform / v7.16.0

Comment: How is the task assigned before you add the identity link? What does the add identity link post return?